# If I pointed a laser directly at Sagittarius A* from Earth, how likely is it to reach the event horizon?

Tags: cosmology, black-holes, spacetime

Given the extreme low-density of space, is it likely to reach the event horizon without interference from other matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sagittarius A* is hidden behind dust clouds that block all visible light. The only reason that we can observe it is that we use infra-red wavelengths that can penetrate the dust clouds. So if you shone a visible laser at Sagittarius A* there is absolutely no chance of it reaching the event horizon.

On the other hand if you use an infra-red laser with a wavelength that can penetrate the dust the laser will almost certain reach Sagittarius A*, or at least reach its accretion disk. Stars may seem big when they're close to you, i.e. the Sun, but compared to average distances between stars they are effectively just points. The chance of your laser hitting a star and being blocked is very small.

Comment: follow-up question to make things interesting ;-) how many photons emitted by the infrared laser would actually reach the black hole? (per watt of laser power, per second of emission time)

Comment: Yeah I'm not convinced even a laser will reach _that_ far before attrition effectively destroys the beam. Not one you can hold in your hand. Sag A* is bl##dy _miles_ away. _But_ I don't know what I'm talking about so an addendum on this topic would be welcome!